# MongoDB - search by date and time using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

Hello I want to find entries between two dates (with time) using C# driver for MongoDB, but the Find + Filter method I use ignores the time and searches by date only (I think). What am I doing wrong?

My POCO:

```
public class TestClassForMongo
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateUtc { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

My search code:

```
IMongoCollection<TestClassForMongo> collection = db.GetCollection<TestClassForMongo>("mongoTest");

var filterBuilder = Builders<TestClassForMongo>.Filter;
var filter = filterBuilder.Gt("CreatedDateUtc", new DateTime(2016, 03, 04, 21, 0, 0)) &
             filterBuilder.Lt("CreatedDateUtc", new DateTime(2016, 03, 04, 22, 0, 0));
List<TestClassForMongo> searchResult = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

The above code returns empty array, although this:

```
collection.Find(filterBuilder.Empty).First().CreatedDateUtc
```

Returns the date: "2016-03-04 21:21:54"

MongoDB 3.2.3, C# MongoDB driver 2.2.3

The driver docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/query/

**THE ANSWER:**

I did not give enough information for anyone to answer this question, the problem was **timezone and UTC related issues**, quite basic ones too. I used `DateTime.UtcNow` to store the date in the database. It is stored as `"CreatedDateUtc" : ISODate("2016-03-04T21:21:54.836Z")`. Getting this in C# returns a date which is actually a UTC date (the `Kind` property is `UTC`), which btw is indicated by the 'Z' suffix of the value in db. Comparing this UTC date with a new DateTime() makes not much sense, as the latter creates a date in your time zone, which can be different than +0 (UTC).

So one option would be to create the date for filter like this:

```
 new DateTime(2016, 03, 04, 21, 0, 0).ToUniversalTime()
```

Or modify the hour part to accomodate the timezone differences, in my example it would be adding 1 hour (as I am in +1 time zone).

So actually the time stored was `22:21:54` in my time zone. If I do a search between 22:00:00 and 23:00:00 using dates created in my time zone, I get the correct results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add BSON attribute on dateTime field (see below),

you can use linqu syntax to build such a query

```
    var min = new DateTime(2016, 03, 03, 22, 0, 0);
    var max = (new DateTime(2016, 03, 03, 23, 0, 0));
    List<TestClassForMongo> searchResult = collection.Find( 
                x => x.CreatedDateUtc > min &
                x.CreatedDateUtc < max
                ).ToList();
```

> BSON ATTRIBUTE

```
public class TestClassForMongo
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions]
    public DateTime CreatedDateUtc { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

> linqPad dump below:

[image: linqPad dump]

Comment: That is correct and I like the linq style, but this did not solve my issue. This is just a different way to create a query (find) basically returning the same thing as the filter builder approach.

Comment: ha! just realized that I didn't put info about BSON attribute - please see in updated answer.

Comment: Does the `BsonDateTimeOptions` do anything without arguments?

Comment: To be honest I added it as seen in one example (but don't remember where).  I even didn't test without it.....

Comment: just made a test on my env (linqPad 5, win10, mongo 3.2.3) and adding/removing attribute was giving me the same output